# Using Grails to output data in columns

Tags: html, grails, html-table

Given a variable amount of data, I want to create a table with fixed number of columns per row. For example, I may only want four columns per row:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>COLUMN_1</th> <th>COLUMN_2</th> <th>COLUMN_3</th> <th>COLUMN_4</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    for(-some code here-) {
    <td>-some output from the loop-</td>
    }
    </tr>
    </table>
```

But as you can see, if the data consisted of 10 elements, the table row will exceed my four columns.

How can I output the data so the number of columns is constant and new rows are created as needed?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Client-side or server-side? Why cannot you just generate a `<tr>` tag after every four cells?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? because to me it sounds like you're using tables for layout, which is a bad idea.

Comment: No, it may look like Im creating a layout. But inside that loop is a data from an array and some from groovy queries which makes the table suitable.  I cant explain it clearly because its too long. But if you have an idea, I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great things about Grails (and Groovy) is its extensibility. Too often developers constrain their thinking to what their tools and frameworks currently provide. I often find it helps to think about what an ideal, more elegant solution would be if it were to be built-in to the framework. That usually gives me a good direction for how I want to implement it. In your scenario, I would prefer a GSP tag that iterates over a collection in groups of elements, so that you can process each group of elements. Something like the following:

```
<table>
<lm:eachGroup size="4" var="row" in="${myCollection}">
   <tr>
   <g:each var="cell" in="${row}">
      <td>${cell}</td>
   </g:each>
   </tr>
</lm:eachGroup>
</table>
```

Of course, that doesn't exist... so I created it! It could be improved by providing a flag to pad the last group of elements so you get a complete row, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

To use my `<lm:eachGroup>` from my taglib in your project you can clone the git repository for my Grails plugin:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/erturne/leapingmindtaglib
```

Package the plugin:

```
$ grails package-plugin
```

Then install it into your app.

BTW, I did something similar a while back to add an eachGroup() method to List.

Answer (score -1):

There’s nothing in HTML that lets you create a column-based table rather than a row-based table.

You’ll need to count how many times you’ve been through the loop, and start a new row after every fourth time through the loop.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work. I am using that code in grails/groovy/gsp. But thanks anyway.

Comment: For me yes, since I'm still new in grails. The code above is part of a bigger code. I am inserting that code in gsp. Inside that loop is another loop which is <g:each .....>. But thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Not quite sure what prompted the downvote just now, but it has put my rep score at a nice even 28,000, so cheers!